# Нужно ли react разработчику хорошее знание css?

Tags: вёрстка, reactjs

Интересует, react разработчики работают с версткой или занимаются непосредственно прописыванием логики? Cтоит ли учить grid flex или это работа верстальщика?

Comment: Плохо себе представляю как верстальщик может верстать в компонентной системе, насквозь пронизанной JS кодом с рендером виртуального DOM-дерева. С другой стороны в большинстве случаев всегда будете работать с простейшей сеткой на типа bootstrap и каким-нибудь UI набором. Но всегда можно встретить и такое: [MaterialUI styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) В любом случае, если вы хотите стать хорошим разработчиком, вам необходимо знать CSS, SCSS/SAAS, LESS, Stylus хотя бы на теоретическом уровне.

Answer (score 3):

Однозначно да.

1. React-разработчик - тоже FE разработчик и стили ему писать тоже надо.
2. Не надо на js городить костыли ради того, что элементарно делается на css.
3. Ну и не везде используется изоляция стилей, так что понимание методологий тоже нужно.